# I want to pass a hidden input when a checkbox is checked. I have make my code for this.But it does not work perfectly

Tags: javascript, php

```
<?php
    $courses_array = array(
       'course_no' => array('E1','E2','E3'), 
       'course_title' => array('A', 'B', 'C'), 
       'course_credit' => array('1','2','3')
    );

    if( !empty($courses_array) ) {
        echo "<input type='checkbox' name='select_all' id='select_all' onClick='select_all_courses(this); check_course_registration_level_complete();' /> Select all <span id='error'> Please Select Courses </span> <br />";
    }
    else {
        echo '<b style="color:green;">There is no courses found for you. <br /> If this problem is not desired please contact with your Course Teacher.</b>';
    }                   
    foreach( $courses_array['course_no'] as $course ) {
    ?>
        <input type='checkbox' name='course[course_no][]' id='course[course_no][]' onClick='check_course_registration_level_complete(); change_hidden_input(this);' value='<?php echo $course; ?>' /> <?php echo $course; ?>
        <input type='hidden' name='course[course_title][]' disabled id='course[course_title][]' value='<?php echo $courses_array['course_title'][ array_search( $course, $courses_array['course_no'] ) ]; ?>'/>
        <input type='hidden' name='course[course_credit][]' disabled id='course[course_credit][]' value='<?php echo $courses_array['course_credit'][ array_search( $course, $courses_array['course_no'] ) ]; ?>'/>
        <input type='hidden' name='course[course_type][]' disabled id='course[course_type][]' value='<?php echo $courses_array['course_type'][ array_search( $course, $courses_array['course_no'] ) ]; ?>'/>
    <?php
    }
    if( !empty($courses_array) ){       
        echo "<br /><br /><input type='submit' name='course_registration_complete' value='Submit'>";    
    }
?>                  

<script>
    function select_all_courses(source){
        var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('course[course_no][]');     
        for(var i=0, n=checkboxes.length; i<n;i++) {
            checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
            document.getElementById('course[course_title][]').disabled = !(source.checked);
            document.getElementById('course[course_credit][]').disabled = !(source.checked);
            document.getElementById('course[course_type][]').disabled = !(source.checked);
        }
    }
</script>

<script>
    function change_hidden_input(course){
        if(course.checked){
            document.getElementById('course[course_title][]').disabled = false;
            document.getElementById('course[course_credit][]').disabled = false;
            document.getElementById('course[course_type][]').disabled = false;
        }else{
            document.getElementById('course[course_title][]').disabled = true;
            document.getElementById('course[course_credit][]').disabled = true;
            document.getElementById('course[course_type][]').disabled = true;
        }
    }
</script>

<script>
    function check_course_registration_level_complete(){
        var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('course[course_no][]');
        var ok = false;
        count = 0;
        for(var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++) {
            if( checkboxes[i].checked ) { 
                ok = true; 
                count++;
                document.getElementById('error').style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
        if( count == checkboxes.length ){
            document.getElementById('select_all').checked = true;
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById('select_all').checked = false;
        }
        if(!ok){
            document.getElementById('error').style.display = 'block';
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Why not just make the value you're putting in the hidden input the value of the checkbox? `<input type="checkbox" name="the-name" value="The value you want to send">` It will get sent if the checkbox is checked, and not sent if it isn't.

Comment: Sorry. First time so i make a fault.
And i solve my problem.